# Can instance attributes be reset properly by a function invoked via ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using the `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()` function to call a method in a class (located in a different file, I don't think this is important). The method call is on the same instance of the class.

My question is: If the method uses class variables, which are reset to default values after the method completes, will there still be any values which are mapped incorrectly by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` map function?

Template code below:

```
import class2 from classFile2
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

c2 = class2()
def eval(values):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        iterator = exe.map(c2.method, values, timeout=0.5, chunksize=1)
```

Will there be any discrepancy between `iterator` and `c2.method(value) for value in values` (not code, but is conceptually understood) if `c2.method` uses class variables which are reset?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mapped incorrectly"?

Comment: Suppose I have `values = [v1,v2]`. If `r1 = c2.method(v1)`, `r2 = c2.method(v2)` and `result = [r1,r2]`, is that equal to `pool.map(c2,method, values, ..)`

Comment: In that case, no they would not be. The problem arises because the single instance of the class is being used concurrently by multiple threads.